# how can i find that which cookies are for logging on website

Tags: cookies, web

Suppose i visit the website `www.example.com` then i can see bunch of cookies in the firebug cookies console.

Now  those cookies are even present when i didn't login.

Now those also have the expiry date of today.

Now when i login then i also see the same cookies.

How can find that which cookies are login purposes.

Comment: "How can find that which cookies are login purposes." Cookies are programmer specification, you need to look at the source code if it not obvious from the name.

Comment: onee thing which i don't understand is that all cookie has expiry date of tday , but if i try the site tomorrow it willagain log me aotomtically even though cookies should have expired by that time

Answer (score 0):

use the FireFox addon Cookie Manager. It has a radio button to display which marks the session